# jquery image slider with rectangular direction flow

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need the image slider like the below image format.[image]

[for ex., If the left arrow clicked, then the items will move left and go bottom direction.]

Any idea would be much helpful. thanks.

Comment: Hi friends, Any more ideas..??

Comment: Hi. I decide that it's intresting thing to do. I am going to write jquery plugin doing that. If you're able to wait with it, write me via mail and i will send you link tomorrow. (I hope this type of question will not be percieved by communite as spum. If that, write i'll delete it)

Comment: I have a slider plugin that allows you to go left or right, it would not be hard to implement up/down if you want. Check it out at https://github.com/ozzyogkush/jquery.contentSlider

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the fact that i liked the idea and wanted to test myself in creating jquery plugins, i made a plugin named Aperture that can be viewed and downloaded at http://itsjoe.de/aperture/demo/

Code and gui are not perfect yet. Let's see if you like it. Improvements could be implemented later.

Github: https://github.com/griffla/jQuery.Aperture

Comment: Nice job. Have you released it under open source license?

Comment: Yes it is. Feel free to use or improve.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking into some custom coding, using the jQuery animate function. You could perform specific animations based on a boxes specific position in the "queue", e.g.

```
$(".arrow").click(function(){
  $(".boxes").each(function(){
    var i = $(this).index(); //get position of box in list of boxes
    if(i == 0){ //first box
      //animate, move down and remove box
    } else if(i == 1) {
      //animate, move down
    } else if(i > 1 && i <= 4) {
      //animate, move left
    } else if(i == 5) {
      //animate, move up
    }
    //create another box to appear on the right and move up
  });
);
```

This is just a very simple idea, there's probably better ways to do this